# Demonstrate a matrix is invertible in different ways

Tags: linear-algebra

Demonstrate that matrix $M$ is invertible using two additional methods of your
choosing other than using the determinant and inverse?

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
    2 & 6\\
    2 & 4
\end{array}\right)$$

$A$ is row-equivalent to the $n$-by-$n$ identity matrix $I$...?
$A$ has $n$ pivot positions...?
The columns of $A$ span $Kn$?

Have no idea how to prove that this another but determinant and inverse....Help with the three question above?

Comment: Do you mean for the particular matrix $\begin{bmatrix}2&6\\2&4\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: It is rank n. Its colums are linearly independent. Its rows are linearly independent.

Comment: Do you mean for the particular matrix [2264]? yes that the correct matrix

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Theinvertiblematrixtheorem